# Need help in breaking out of a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

the get_valid_user_input() function works on its own.  But while calling it in the enter_new_trade() function , the loop keeps repeating.  The program need to exit the loop once a user enters a single trade.

```
def get_valid_user_input():
    
    valid_input = False
    
    while not valid_input:
        ticker = input("Enter a Ticker")
        if ticker == "":
            print("Ticker cannot be blank")
            
        else:
            b_s = ['b','s']
            buy_sell = input("Buy or Sell").lower()
            while buy_sell not in b_s:
                print("Please enter b or s")
                buy_sell = input("Buy or Sell").lower()
                
            # validating the Quantity of Stock
            valid_integer = False
            while not valid_integer:
                try:
                    stock_qty = int(input("Quantity of Stock "))
                    if stock_qty < 0:
                        print("Please enter a positive whole number")
                    else:
                        valid_integer = True

                except ValueError:
                    print("Please enter a positive whole number")

            # validating the Price of stock
            valid_float = False
            while not valid_float:
                try:
                    floating = float(input("Total Cost (including brokerage):"))
                    if floating < 0:
                        print("Price cannot be negative")
                    else:
                        valid_float = True
                
                except ValueError:
                    print("Enter a valid price")
                    
            valid_date = False
            while not valid_date:
                try:
                    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(input("Date"),"%Y-%m-%d").date()
                    valid_date = True
                except:
                    print("Enter the date format in yyyy-mm-dd")
            
            break
            
            valid_input = True
            
get_valid_user_input()
print("All user inputs validated")

# Manually enter new trade
def enter_new_trade():
    
    trading_data = []
    
    choice = input("Are you looking to buy or sell stocks? (b/s)?").lower()
    while choice:
        if choice == 'b':
            ticker = get_valid_user_input()
            buy_sell = get_valid_user_input()
            stock_qty = get_valid_user_input()
            stock_price = get_valid_user_input()
            Date = get_valid_user_input()
            print(f"{Date} {ticker}   BUY   {stock_qty} for $   {stock_price}") 

            trading_data.append([ticker,buy_sell,stock_qty,stock_price,Date])
            

        elif choice == 's':
            ticker = get_valid_user_input()
            buy_sell = get_valid_user_input()
            stock_qty = get_valid_user_input()
            stock_price = get_valid_user_input()
            Date = get_valid_user_input()
            print(f"{Date} {ticker}   SELL   {stock_qty} for $   {stock_price}")
            trading_data.append([ticker,buy_sell,stock_qty,stock_price,Date])

    #else:
    #    print("Invalid Input")
        choice = input("Are you looking to buy or sell stocks? (b/s)?").lower()

        #break
        return trading_data

enter_new_trade()
print("Trades are added to the system")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `break` keywork to break out of loop and print the `Exception` after catching them to see what the actual exception is.

```
import sys
import datetime

def get_valid_user_input():


    valid_input = False

    while not valid_input:
        ticker = input("Enter a Ticker")
        if ticker == "":
            print("Ticker cannot be blank")

        else:
            b_s = ['b', 's']
            buy_sell = input("Buy or Sell").lower()
            while buy_sell not in b_s:
                print("Please enter b or s")
                buy_sell = input("Buy or Sell").lower()

            # validating the Quantity of Stock
            valid_integer = False
            while not valid_integer:
                try:
                    stock_qty = int(input("Quantity of Stock "))
                    if stock_qty < 0:
                        print("Please enter a positive whole number")
                    else:
                        valid_integer = True

                except ValueError:
                    print("Please enter a positive whole number")

            # validating the Price of stock
            valid_float = False
            while not valid_float:
                try:
                    floating = float(input("Total Cost (including brokerage):"))
                    if floating < 0:
                        print("Price cannot be negative")
                    else:
                        valid_float = True

                except ValueError:
                    print("Enter a valid price")

            valid_date = False
            while not valid_date:
                try:
                    data = input("Date (yyyy-mm-dd) :").strip()
                    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(data, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                    valid_date = True
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    print(f"Enter the date format in yyyy-mm-dd invalid date >>>{data}<<<")

            valid_input = True

    return ticker, buy_sell, stock_qty, floating, date



def enter_new_trade():
    trading_data = []

    choice = False
    while not choice:

        choice = input("Are you looking to buy or sell stocks? (b/s)? ").lower()

        if choice == 'b':
            ticker, buy_sell, stock_qty, stock_price, _date = get_valid_user_input()
            print(f"{_date} {ticker}   BUY   {stock_qty} for $   {stock_price}")
            trading_data.append([ticker, buy_sell, stock_qty, stock_price, _date])
            break
        elif choice == 's':
            ticker, buy_sell, stock_qty, stock_price, _date = get_valid_user_input()
            print(f"{_date} {ticker}   SELL   {stock_qty} for $   {stock_price}")
            trading_data.append([ticker, buy_sell, stock_qty, stock_price, _date])
            break
        else:
            print(f"Invalid input {choice}")
            choice = False

    return trading_data

def main():
    print(enter_new_trade())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
Are you looking to buy or sell stocks? (b/s)? b
Enter a Ticker33
Buy or Sellb
Quantity of Stock 33
Total Cost (including brokerage):555
Date (yyyy-mm-dd) :2022-10-20
2022-10-20 33   BUY   33 for $   555.0
[['33', 'b', 33, 555.0, datetime.date(2022, 10, 20)]]
```

Comment: I tried that too, but it did not work

Comment: I tried it with suggested changes, it still keeps looping :/

Comment: It does work now, however the catch is, I am not supposed to use  , while True: ----,
The criteria for me is to use a condition with the while , instead of while True .

Comment: I made the following changes 
 
choice = False
    while not choice: 
------


and it works now. Thanks alot @dev